# How to fetch custom table value from databse

Tags: magento2

Hi all i have a custom module check the screenshot below:-

[image]

now i have created a custom table in database with name the learn_checkdelivery here is the screenhsot

[image]

now i want these pincodes value in the database is to be reflected in my backend module field with the name Postcode.
how to achieve this any suggestion or help.
Thanks in Advance

**Update**

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">

    <system>
        <tab id="learn" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
            <label>Learn</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="checkDelivery" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Check Delivery</label>
            <tab>learn</tab>
            <resource>Learn_CheckDelivery::config_checkdelivery</resource>
            <group id="config" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Check delivery postcode</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="postcodes" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Postcodes</label>
                    <comment>Comma-separated</comment>
                    <depends><field id="enable">1</field></depends>
                </field>
                <field id="success_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="21" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Available</label>
                    <depends><field id="enable">1</field></depends>
                </field>
                <field id="error_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="22" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Unavailable</label>
                    <depends><field id="enable">1</field></depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>

    </system>
</config>
```

**Learn/CheckDelivery/Model/Pincode.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Model;

class Pincode extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Pincode');
    }
}
```

**Learn/CheckDelivery/Model/ResourceModel/Pincode.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel;

class Pincode extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('learn_checkdelivery', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Learn/CheckDelivery/Model/ResourceModel/Pincode/Collection.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Pincode;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection 
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\Pincode','Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Pincode');
    }
}
```

**update**

**Textarea.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\Form\Element;

class Textarea extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Textarea
{
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $factoryElement,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\CollectionFactory $factoryCollection,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\Pincode $pincode,
        $data = []
    ) 
    {
        $this->pincode = $pincode
        parent::__construct($factoryElement, $factoryCollection, $escaper, $data);
        $this->setType('text');
        $this->setExtType('textfield');
    }

    public function getHtml()
    {
        $data = $this->pincode->getCollection()->getColumnValues('pincode');
        $data = implode(', ', $data);

        $this->addClass('input-text admin__control-text');

        $this->setValue($data);
        return parent::getHtml();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want 'learn_checkdelivery' tables value in postcode system config ?

Comment: yes exactly this is what i want

Comment: update your question with code of system.xml

Comment: okay wait am on it

Comment: @Hiren please check my updated question

Comment: have you created model, resource model and collection ?

Comment: yes i have am sharing those also wait

Comment: check my updated question thanks

Comment: @Hiren kindly check my updated question

Comment: missing semicolon in $this->pincode = $pincode line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your **system.xml** as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">

    <system>
        <tab id="learn" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
            <label>Learn</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="checkDelivery" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Check Delivery</label>
            <tab>learn</tab>
            <resource>Learn_CheckDelivery::config_checkdelivery</resource>
            <group id="config" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Check delivery postcode</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="postcodes" translate="label" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Form\Element\Textarea" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Postcodes</label>
                    <comment>Comma-separated</comment>
                    <depends><field id="enable">1</field></depends>
                </field>
                <field id="success_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="21" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Available</label>
                    <depends><field id="enable">1</field></depends>
                </field>
                <field id="error_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="22" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Unavailable</label>
                    <depends><field id="enable">1</field></depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>

    </system>
</config>
```

Add following file **Vendor\Module\Model\Form\Element\Textarea.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Form\Element;

class Textarea extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Textarea
{
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $factoryElement,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\CollectionFactory $factoryCollection,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\Pincode $pincode,
        $data = []
    ) 
    {
        $this->pincode = $pincode;
        parent::__construct($factoryElement, $factoryCollection, $escaper, $data);
        $this->setType('text');
        $this->setExtType('textfield');
    }

    public function getHtml()
    {
        $data = $this->pincode->getCollection()->getColumnValues('pincode');
        $data = implode(', ', $data);

        $this->addClass('input-text admin__control-text');

        $this->setValue($data);
        return parent::getHtml();
    }
}
```

This will give you what exactly you want :D

Comment: is my model resource model and collection file is correct ??

Comment: have you got any errors ? you can follow Amit Bera's answer for model, resource model and collection

Comment: what changes have you made in system.xml file?/

Comment: i have added 'Vendor\Module\Model\Form\Element\Textarea' as type, you can check code for further

Comment: @Pramod upvote and accept if it helps you !

Comment: Textarea is a directory??and what should be the name of this file

Comment: you have to create Textarea.php file under Vendor\Module\Model\Form\Element with the given code

Comment: yes i got it when i checked system.xml file

Comment: am getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in E:\xampp\htdocs\pramod\app\code\Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\Form\Element\Textarea.php on line 12

Comment: its semicolon mistake you can solve this by yourself, anyway i have updated the answer

Comment: i have tried that and it didint work

Comment: what error are you facing now?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'parent' (T_STRING) in E:\xampp\htdocs\pramod\app\code\Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\Form\Element\Textarea.php on line 17

Comment: updated the answer, check now

Comment: this works like a charm thankss bro

Comment: Happy to help you

Comment: after the above changes i cant add values manually in the admin postcode area as changes are not showing over there??any idea why

Comment: sorry i don't get you ?

Comment: i mean the solution works but when i enter something in backend in that post form then am not able to save those values as it is only taking up values from database

Comment: yes because  $this->setValue($data); set the data each time when you open this config page.

Comment: then if i comment out this line will solve this issue??

Comment: no, this is the main line of code as per your req. this set the DB table data, you have to apply some logic here

Comment: right i need some alternate method here

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104131/discussion-on-answer-by-hiren-how-to-fetch-custom-table-value-from-databse).

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get fetch data from a  database table , then you have to create

1. Create a Model;
2. Create a Resource Model
3. Create Resource Model Collection

Magento2 use [**MVVM architecture**](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/),So you need to work on model section  which includes **Model, Resource Model,Resource Model Collection** Class.

#### **Model** Class:

**file Location:** `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/Model/{YourModel}.php`.

```
 <?php

/**
 * Create model  name of Student
 */
namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Model;


class {YourModel} extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Map Resource Class At Model lass
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\{YourModel}::class);
    }
}
```

#### Resource Model Class

**file Location:** `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/Model/ResourceModel/{YourResourceModelName}.php`

**And code:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Create Resource Model name for model  Student \StackExchange\Example\Model\Student
 * As Model name Student then Resource model is Student
 */

namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel;


class {YourResourceModelName} extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

    /**
     * Define table for this Resource model
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
       $this->_init('learn_checkdelivery', 'id');
    }

}
```

#### Resource Model Collection

**File Location:** `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/Model/ResourceModel/{YourResourceModelName}/Collection.php`

**And Code**

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\{YourResourceModelName};


class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

   /**
    * Map Model CLass and Resource mode Class at COllection Class
    */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
                \{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Model\{YourModel}::class,
                 \{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\{YourResourceModelName}::class
                );
    }

}
```

After that using the Resource Collection model and Model Class you fetch data from that table.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html#step-2-create-model

Comment: i have already tried this way and its not working

Comment: Please share your of these classes,I will check

Comment: check my updated question thanks